# Setting height of a bootstrap column element

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```css
.orDivText{
 padding:20%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
      <div class="orDivText">or</div>
     </div>
```

[image]

I feel its not giving full height. How can i fix it to utilize complete space?

Comment: complete space in the sense of vertically or horizontally? can you please elaborate.

Comment: Looks full height to me...

Comment: Vertical height if col-md is used should be actually 69.xxx px but here its only 60px. So I am wondering why is it happening so?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 orDivText">
</div>
```

You can try it like this.

Comment: if you fix it manually then it might not be responsive any more!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the column adapts based on whats inside it. You can alter this by adding a seperate sub class to the column and then altering the height here manually.

eg:

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 height">
                        <div class="orDivText">or</div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.height {
height: 60px
}
```

define the new class either on the page within `<style>` tags or preferably add a new external style sheet. Just be sure to link the new style sheet AFTER the bootstrap one.